# Open a PDF which is password protected

Tags: pdf, decryption

One day ago, I downloaded a PDF that requires a password. Then I searched for software to decrypt the password that's called `pdfcrack`.
Then I installed `pdfcrack` and ran a command in the Terminal:

```
pdfcrack -f encrypted.pdf
```

My doubt is when it completes in days or months or years

Answer (score 1):

It depends. It depends on your hardware, the strength of the encryption algorithm and the length of the password.

Also Ask Ubuntu is not the place for questions like these. You might want to try Crypto Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you really have the rights to do it, better don't ask at all.

Ask the issuer of the PDF for an unprotected version. And you better provide a good reason for that.